# "That" instead of "those" with plural nouns

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns, grammatical-number, demonstrative-pronouns

At the first glance, *that* is used with singular nouns, and *those* with plural.

However, sometimes I see that *that* is used with plural nouns as well.

So, both of these examples seems to be correct:

The obvious one:

> The car that belongs to me needs to be repaired.

The not-so-obvious one:

> The cars that belong to me need to be repaired. (*That*, not *those*.)

External references:

1. https://www.englishforums.com/English/ThatVsThose/pxnwl/post.htm
2. A quote from LibreOffice Writer user guide:

> You can easily check which properties are specific to a style by looking at the Contains section of
>   the Organizer page. If you want to reset the ***properties*** of a child style to ***that*** of the parent style,
>   click the Standard button located at the bottom of each Paragraph and Character style dialog.

3. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-pronouns

How can I understand should I use "that" or "those" in such cases?

Comment: *the properties* should definitely take *those*, but many people do not really understand the *that of* construction.  (Rod Serling set a bad example with the opening narration of *The Twilight Zone*: “…whose boundaries are *that* of imagination.”)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these sentences, **that** is a conjunction. It introduces a [relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses). **That** only needs to change to **those** when it's an adjective modifying a plural noun or a pronoun referring to a plural antecedent.

> The car **that** belongs to me needs to be repaired.
>   The cars **that** belong to me need to be repaired.

The sentence from the LibreOffice Writer user's guide is an error. It should say:

> If you want to reset the **properties** of a child style to **those** of the parent style, click the Standard button located at the bottom of each Paragraph and Character style dialog.

By the way, **that** can also be an adverb. When it's an adverb, it also doesn't agree in number with anything else. For example:

> My car isn't **that** fast.
>   My cars aren't **that** fast.